# How to locate Magento\Catalog\Model\Category in my Magento 2 file system

Tags: linux, magento, find

I am trying to debug an problem on a Magento 2.  I have an error message that mentions the folder Magento\Catalog\Model\Category so I am trying to find this folder to help with debugging.  This is either a Magento 2 problem of a general Linux problem depending on if this folder is part of the standard Magento 2 setup or possibly part of an extension.  If it standard I would like to find where this folder is, and if it is not I would like to know the correct Linux command to find it.

I tried the command

find / -type d -name 'Magento'

This caused the entire screen fill with permission denied messages.  I tried the command to exclude permission denied messages

find / -type d -name 'Magento' 2>/dev/null

This gave nothing which seems to indicate 'Magento' is in a folder that doesn't have read permissions.  I looking for advice either on where to look for this folder or on how to temporarily override read permissions in the find command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If install magento follow this way https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/composer.html?lang=en, Magento\Catalog\Model\Category  should be vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category.php
2. for the magento2 github, it should be https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category.php

Comment: Thank you.  I figured out that the namespace isn't always the same as the file path, and the namespace gets converted by the autoload class.  In this case that is Magento/Catalog gets replaced by magento/module-catalog, and Category gets replaced by Category.php.